# No member named 'source' in 'udphdr'

Tags: c++, gcc, udp

I am trying to install [palmtree](http://nsrg.louisiana.edu/project/ntmaps/output/palmtree.html) and I followed every step but when I run make, I obtained the following error:

```
Building file: ../src/tools/palmtree/PalmTree.cpp
Invoking: GCC C++ Compiler
g++ -O3 -Wall -c -fmessage-length=0 -m32 -MMD -MP -MF"src/tools/palmtree/PalmTree.d" -MT"src/tools/palmtree/PalmTree.d" -o"src/tools/palmtree/PalmTree.o" "../src/tools/palmtree/PalmTree.cpp"
Finished building: ../src/tools/palmtree/PalmTree.cpp

Building file: ../src/tools/Tool.cpp
Invoking: GCC C++ Compiler
g++ -O3 -Wall -c -fmessage-length=0 -m32 -MMD -MP -MF"src/tools/Tool.d" -MT"src/tools/Tool.d" -o"src/tools/Tool.o" "../src/tools/Tool.cpp"
Finished building: ../src/tools/Tool.cpp

Building file: ../src/prober/udp/DirectUDPProber.cpp
Invoking: GCC C++ Compiler
g++ -O3 -Wall -c -fmessage-length=0 -m32 -MMD -MP -MF"src/prober/udp/DirectUDPProber.d" -MT"src/prober/udp/DirectUDPProber.d" -o"src/prober/udp/DirectUDPProber.o" "../src/prober/udp/DirectUDPProber.cpp"
../src/prober/udp/DirectUDPProber.cpp:201:8: error: no member named 'source' in 'udphdr'
         udp->source=htons(srcPort_16);
         ~~~  ^
../src/prober/udp/DirectUDPProber.cpp:202:8: error: no member named 'dest' in 'udphdr'
         udp->dest=htons(dstPort_16);
         ~~~  ^
../src/prober/udp/DirectUDPProber.cpp:203:8: error: no member named 'len' in 'udphdr'
         udp->len=htons(DirectProber::MINIMUM_UDP_HEADER_LENGTH + DirectProber::DEFAULT_UDP_RANDOM_DATA_LENGTH + DirectProber::ATTENTION_MESSAGE.length());//the length must be udp_header length + data length.
         ~~~  ^
../src/prober/udp/DirectUDPProber.cpp:204:8: error: no member named 'check' in 'udphdr'
         udp->check=0x0;
         ~~~  ^
../src/prober/udp/DirectUDPProber.cpp:225:25: error: no member named 'len' in 'udphdr'
         memcpy(pseudo, &(udp->len), 2);
                          ~~~  ^
../src/prober/udp/DirectUDPProber.cpp:233:8: error: no member named 'check' in 'udphdr'
         udp->check=DirectProber::calculateInternetChecksum((uint16_t *)pseudoBuffer, pseudoBufferLength);
         ~~~  ^
../src/prober/udp/DirectUDPProber.cpp:406:20: error: member access into incomplete type 'struct icmphdr'
                        tmpChecksum=icmp->checksum;
                                        ^
../src/prober/udp/DirectUDPProber.cpp:402:11: note: forward declaration of 'icmphdr'
                        struct icmphdr * icmp=(struct icmphdr *)(buffer + (ip->ip_hl)*4);
                               ^
../src/prober/udp/DirectUDPProber.cpp:407:8: error: member access into incomplete type 'struct icmphdr'
                        icmp->checksum=0x0;//before computing checksum, the sum field must be zero
                            ^
../src/prober/udp/DirectUDPProber.cpp:402:11: note: forward declaration of 'icmphdr'
                        struct icmphdr * icmp=(struct icmphdr *)(buffer + (ip->ip_hl)*4);
                               ^
../src/prober/udp/DirectUDPProber.cpp:415:8: error: member access into incomplete type 'struct icmphdr'
                        icmp->checksum=tmpChecksum;
                            ^
../src/prober/udp/DirectUDPProber.cpp:402:11: note: forward declaration of 'icmphdr'
                        struct icmphdr * icmp=(struct icmphdr *)(buffer + (ip->ip_hl)*4);
                               ^
../src/prober/udp/DirectUDPProber.cpp:420:11: error: member access into incomplete type 'struct icmphdr'
                        if(icmp->type==DirectProber::ICMP_TYPE_TIME_EXCEEDED || icmp->type == DirectProber::ICMP_TYPE_DESTINATION_UNREACHABLE){
                               ^
../src/prober/udp/DirectUDPProber.cpp:402:11: note: forward declaration of 'icmphdr'
                        struct icmphdr * icmp=(struct icmphdr *)(buffer + (ip->ip_hl)*4);
                               ^
../src/prober/udp/DirectUDPProber.cpp:439:25: error: no member named 'source' in 'udphdr'
                                                ntohs(payloadudp->source)==srcPort_16 &&
                                                      ~~~~~~~~~~  ^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.11.sdk/usr/include/sys/_endian.h:132:39: note: expanded from macro 'ntohs'
#define ntohs(x)        __DARWIN_OSSwapInt16(x)
                                             ^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.11.sdk/usr/include/libkern/_OSByteOrder.h:72:40: note: expanded from macro '__DARWIN_OSSwapInt16'
    ((__uint16_t)(__builtin_constant_p(x) ? __DARWIN_OSSwapConstInt16(x) : _OSSwapInt16(x)))
                                       ^
../src/prober/udp/DirectUDPProber.cpp:439:25: error: no member named 'source' in 'udphdr'
                                                ntohs(payloadudp->source)==srcPort_16 &&
                                                      ~~~~~~~~~~  ^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.11.sdk/usr/include/sys/_endian.h:132:39: note: expanded from macro 'ntohs'
#define ntohs(x)        __DARWIN_OSSwapInt16(x)
                                             ^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.11.sdk/usr/include/libkern/_OSByteOrder.h:72:71: note: expanded from macro '__DARWIN_OSSwapInt16'
    ((__uint16_t)(__builtin_constant_p(x) ? __DARWIN_OSSwapConstInt16(x) : _OSSwapInt16(x)))
                                                                      ^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.11.sdk/usr/include/libkern/_OSByteOrder.h:44:34: note: expanded from macro '__DARWIN_OSSwapConstInt16'
    ((__uint16_t)((((__uint16_t)(x) & 0xff00) >> 8) | \
                                 ^
../src/prober/udp/DirectUDPProber.cpp:439:25: error: no member named 'source' in 'udphdr'
                                                ntohs(payloadudp->source)==srcPort_16 &&
                                                      ~~~~~~~~~~  ^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.11.sdk/usr/include/sys/_endian.h:132:39: note: expanded from macro 'ntohs'
#define ntohs(x)        __DARWIN_OSSwapInt16(x)
                                             ^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.11.sdk/usr/include/libkern/_OSByteOrder.h:72:71: note: expanded from macro '__DARWIN_OSSwapInt16'
    ((__uint16_t)(__builtin_constant_p(x) ? __DARWIN_OSSwapConstInt16(x) : _OSSwapInt16(x)))
                                                                      ^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.11.sdk/usr/include/libkern/_OSByteOrder.h:45:32: note: expanded from macro '__DARWIN_OSSwapConstInt16'
                (((__uint16_t)(x) & 0x00ff) << 8)))
                               ^
../src/prober/udp/DirectUDPProber.cpp:439:25: error: no member named 'source' in 'udphdr'
                                                ntohs(payloadudp->source)==srcPort_16 &&
                                                      ~~~~~~~~~~  ^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.11.sdk/usr/include/sys/_endian.h:132:39: note: expanded from macro 'ntohs'
#define ntohs(x)        __DARWIN_OSSwapInt16(x)
                                             ^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.11.sdk/usr/include/libkern/_OSByteOrder.h:72:89: note: expanded from macro '__DARWIN_OSSwapInt16'
    ((__uint16_t)(__builtin_constant_p(x) ? __DARWIN_OSSwapConstInt16(x) : _OSSwapInt16(x)))
                                                                                        ^
../src/prober/udp/DirectUDPProber.cpp:440:25: error: no member named 'dest' in 'udphdr'
                                                ntohs(payloadudp->dest)==dstPort_16){
                                                      ~~~~~~~~~~  ^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.11.sdk/usr/include/sys/_endian.h:132:39: note: expanded from macro 'ntohs'
#define ntohs(x)        __DARWIN_OSSwapInt16(x)
                                             ^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.11.sdk/usr/include/libkern/_OSByteOrder.h:72:40: note: expanded from macro '__DARWIN_OSSwapInt16'
    ((__uint16_t)(__builtin_constant_p(x) ? __DARWIN_OSSwapConstInt16(x) : _OSSwapInt16(x)))
                                       ^
../src/prober/udp/DirectUDPProber.cpp:440:25: error: no member named 'dest' in 'udphdr'
                                                ntohs(payloadudp->dest)==dstPort_16){
                                                      ~~~~~~~~~~  ^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.11.sdk/usr/include/sys/_endian.h:132:39: note: expanded from macro 'ntohs'
#define ntohs(x)        __DARWIN_OSSwapInt16(x)
                                             ^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.11.sdk/usr/include/libkern/_OSByteOrder.h:72:71: note: expanded from macro '__DARWIN_OSSwapInt16'
    ((__uint16_t)(__builtin_constant_p(x) ? __DARWIN_OSSwapConstInt16(x) : _OSSwapInt16(x)))
                                                                      ^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.11.sdk/usr/include/libkern/_OSByteOrder.h:44:34: note: expanded from macro '__DARWIN_OSSwapConstInt16'
    ((__uint16_t)((((__uint16_t)(x) & 0xff00) >> 8) | \
                                 ^
../src/prober/udp/DirectUDPProber.cpp:440:25: error: no member named 'dest' in 'udphdr'
                                                ntohs(payloadudp->dest)==dstPort_16){
                                                      ~~~~~~~~~~  ^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.11.sdk/usr/include/sys/_endian.h:132:39: note: expanded from macro 'ntohs'
#define ntohs(x)        __DARWIN_OSSwapInt16(x)
                                             ^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.11.sdk/usr/include/libkern/_OSByteOrder.h:72:71: note: expanded from macro '__DARWIN_OSSwapInt16'
    ((__uint16_t)(__builtin_constant_p(x) ? __DARWIN_OSSwapConstInt16(x) : _OSSwapInt16(x)))
                                                                      ^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.11.sdk/usr/include/libkern/_OSByteOrder.h:45:32: note: expanded from macro '__DARWIN_OSSwapConstInt16'
                (((__uint16_t)(x) & 0x00ff) << 8)))
                               ^
../src/prober/udp/DirectUDPProber.cpp:440:25: error: no member named 'dest' in 'udphdr'
                                                ntohs(payloadudp->dest)==dstPort_16){
                                                      ~~~~~~~~~~  ^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.11.sdk/usr/include/sys/_endian.h:132:39: note: expanded from macro 'ntohs'
#define ntohs(x)        __DARWIN_OSSwapInt16(x)
                                             ^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.11.sdk/usr/include/libkern/_OSByteOrder.h:72:89: note: expanded from macro '__DARWIN_OSSwapInt16'
    ((__uint16_t)(__builtin_constant_p(x) ? __DARWIN_OSSwapConstInt16(x) : _OSSwapInt16(x)))
                                                                                        ^
../src/prober/udp/DirectUDPProber.cpp:456:81: error: member access into incomplete type 'struct icmphdr'
                                                                return buildProbeRecord(REQTime, dst, rplyAddress, TTL, ip->ip_ttl, icmp->type, icmp->code,  ntohs(ip->ip_id), payloadip->ip_ttl, RRarray,RRarrayLength);
                                                                                                                                        ^
../src/prober/udp/DirectUDPProber.cpp:402:11: note: forward declaration of 'icmphdr'
                        struct icmphdr * icmp=(struct icmphdr *)(buffer + (ip->ip_hl)*4);
                               ^
fatal error: too many errors emitted, stopping now [-ferror-limit=]
20 errors generated.
make: *** [src/prober/udp/DirectUDPProber.o] Error 1
```

I understand that I need to change something within ../src/prober/udp/DirectUDPProber.cpp, I assume that the type is defined within: 
`#include <netinet/udp.h>` I used locate to find `netinet/udp.h` it gave:

```
(1) /Applications/MATLAB_R2015a.app/polyspace/verifier/cxx/include/include-libc/netinet/ip_icmp.h
(2) /Applications/MATLAB_R2016a.app/polyspace/verifier/cxx/include/include-libc/netinet/ip_icmp.h
(3) /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/AppleTVSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/AppleTVSimulator.sdk/usr/include/netinet/ip_icmp.h
(4) /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.11.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Kernel.framework/Versions/A/Headers/netinet/ip_icmp.h
(5) /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.11.sdk/usr/include/netinet/ip_icmp.h
(6) /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/WatchSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/WatchSimulator.sdk/usr/include/netinet/ip_icmp.h
(7) /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator.sdk/usr/include/netinet/ip_icmp.h
(8) /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/swift-migrator/sdk/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/netinet/ip_icmp.h
(9) /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/swift-migrator/sdk/iPhoneSimulator.sdk/usr/include/netinet/ip_icmp.h
```

I looked at the 3rd one and the 8th one, and indeed they have only:

```
struct udphdr {
    u_short uh_sport;       /* source port */
    u_short uh_dport;       /* destination port */
    u_short uh_ulen;        /* udp length */
    u_short uh_sum;         /* udp checksum */
};
```

While the matlab link has:

```
/* UDP header as specified by RFC 768, August 1980. */
#ifdef __FAVOR_BSD

struct udphdr
{
  u_int16_t uh_sport;       /* source port */
  u_int16_t uh_dport;       /* destination port */
  u_int16_t uh_ulen;        /* udp length */
  u_int16_t uh_sum;     /* udp checksum */
};

#else

struct udphdr
{
  u_int16_t source;
  u_int16_t dest;
  u_int16_t len;
  u_int16_t check;
};
#endif
```

What should I do? they mention that I should have pthread library, but I could not find much information.

Thank you for your help.

Antoine

Comment: First you'll need to go to `DirectUDPProber.cpp` and around line 201 find `udp->source=htons(srcPort_16);`. Then go up to see what type is `udp`. Then you need to find out whether this type has member called `source` for real. This would be a good starting point for the discussion.

Comment: I could not edit my post, thus please see below the answer to your question.

Comment: You should always be able to edit your post as long as you logged in, by clicking small "edit" at the bottom, just below the tags (in web version of StackOverflow). I strongly suggest you to move your new information there, as the answer in it's current form may upset other users.

Comment: The quote from the website: "System Requirements and Notes: Linux 32 bits OS". It seems that you are on Mac, and it is probably the problem. Mac OS X is a flavor of BSD (`__FAVOR_BSD` is defined), so definition of `struct udphdr`is different than those on Linux (POSIX version). You may need to port your application to Mac yourself. The is a small chance that you can make it work by forcing using POSIX version of struct (if it exists on Mac at all). See for example [here](https://sourceware.org/ml/libc-alpha/2013-12/msg00632.html)

Comment: The easiest solution would be to install [Linux](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop) on a [virtual machine](https://www.virtualbox.org/) and to try to run your experiments there